# Javascript function to count loaded and/or complete images executes very slow on mobile

Tags: javascript

This works well on all the desktop browsers I've tested, but on mobile browsers it usually jumps directly from 0% to 100% when the page has loaded, or it only shows one or two numbers in between like 0%, 30%, 67%, 100%, for example.

I wondered if there was a way to make the image counting function execute as smoothly on mobile as it does on desktop.

Comment: I'd suggest assigning to `.innerHTML` only when you have HTML markup to insert - otherwise, it's generally easier and safer to use `.textContent`.

Comment: I've updated my answer with a bit more explanations. Also, you should really edit your question and add back the code. Without that, others couldn't possibly give advice because they'd have no idea what you are currently doing so how could they make suggestions on how to improve it?

Answer (score 1):

While you do have some issues that can improve performance (listed below), let's first address the fact that it is entirely reasonable to assume that you could go from 0% to 100% very quickly (so quickly that you wouldn't see the interim values) on mobile, but not that quickly on a desktop.

Images in a web page download in parallel, so the number going from 0% to 100% isn't a real shocker since multiple images may complete loading at or near simultaneous times.

It's also common for sites to serve larger image files to desktop users than are served to mobile users. So, again, it's perfectly reasonable to see the desktop site taking longer to load than the mobile site and therefore, you'd see the percent complete running through more increments than on mobile.

Lastly, you can't just test this on your own desktop and your own mobile device. Different Internet speeds for desktops and for mobile devices apply and hardware configurations play a part here too. You'd really need to test this across a variety of desktops and a variety of mobile devices to know if there really is an issue or not.

---

### With all that said, there are a few things about your code that you should modify...

Your script appears to loop through all the images just once, so it's not clear how it'w working at all because looping over the images just once would only give you a snapshot of what % was loaded at the time the loop ran. I would instead set up a `load` event handler for each image and update the loaded count and the overall progress there. In that event handler, you don't need to test for `.complete` because the `.load` event only fires when the image is finished loading.

Also, **[`getElementsByTagName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByTagName)** returns **[a live node list](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList)** that hinders performance by having to re-scan the DOM for all the elements each time you access the node list variable. If you are not dealing with dynamically loaded or removed images, this can be a big waste. Use **[`querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)** instead.

Lastly, **[`.innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML)** parses the supplied string for HTML, which is wasteful if there isn't any HTML to parse. When there is no HTML, use **[`.textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent)**.

```
// Place all the image elements into an Array
var imglist = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll("img"));
var numb = parent.document.getElementById("numb");
var imglistlength = imglist.length;
var start = 0;

// Loop over all the image elements
imgList.forEach(function(i){
  // Set up a load event handler for each
  i.addEventListener("load", function(){
    // If you are here, an image finished loading.
    // Just increase the count and update the percent
    numb.textContent = Math.round((++start / imglistlength) * 100);
  });
});
```

Comment: @user9525118  You do know that images download in parallel, right? It is entirely reasonable to assume that you could go from 0% to 100% very quickly (so quickly that you wouldn't see the interim values).